# Full Example of Coinbase API?

Tags: html, json

I realize this may be asking a lot but the API they provide is really only a few lines.  I just want to see how to put it all together and call it in the HTML. I think seeing a full example would help me a lot!

What I know I need:
I need to request the url

```
 $.getJSON("https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?api_key=XXX"
```

That provides the validation I need, as well as accessing the API( I think).  The rest of the code they provide on their site are the methods.

```
# Reponse
{
  "amount": "10.00",
  "currency": "USD"
}
```

So to call in HTML I could use a

```
<div id="call"></div>
```

I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: I am afraid that you cant use javascript to retrieve the spot rate since browsers do not comply with cross domain request. You need to use a server side language.

Comment: Their partial example was using json.

Comment: Could you post the example?

Answer (score 0):

You can add &callback=? to the url as shown in this jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/8N7an/

```
$.getJSON("https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?currency=USD&callback=?", function( data ) {
    //Do what you want with the response here
});
```

Otherwise, you'll run into a cross origin request issue that would require server side access to fix.

So in your case the URL would be:
https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?currency=USD&callback=?

I don't think you need an API key for this call. In fact, if you're doing this in javascript/jQuery, it's probably best not to store the API key on the page since it would be easy to expose.

Hope this helps.